# Zencart Subscribe to newsletter

Tags: php, shopping-cart, zen-cart

There is subscribe to newsletter functionality in latest zencart i.e. 1.9
But we can only send newsletter to registered users.
I want to send newsletters to people who just subscribe , not register.
There are certain module like [this](http://www.zen-cart.com/index.php?main_page=product_contrib_info&products_id=106) , but its too painful , lots of code change etc etc.
Is there any change which will allow use to add in db for newsletter subscription and if user want to register on site , it will not create problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an external-to-Zen Cart newsletter program such as MailChimp, you can accomplish this.  I have an integration for MailChimp which is available in the Zen Cart free software add ons here:

http://www.zen-cart.com/index.php?main_page=product_contrib_info&products_id=632

There is also one for Constant Contact, or you could ask another email service provider (if you find one you like) to provide a small code fragement for you - they may have a ready to go integration.

Comment: Thank you @Scott , will use it And let you know.

Comment: Dude @Scott , MailChimp have limit for free newsletters.I really don't want to pay.Finally installed same plugin .